# Calculate the probability of one ball out of 5 being number 80

Tags: probability, statistics

Im trying to write a lottery game program and want to have probabilities calculated for the players before they choose numbers.

Lottery rules:

```
5 Total Balls
Each ball has to be a number between 1 and 80
No ball can repeat on one drawing (5,10,20,55,55) would not happen
```

I want to calculate the probability of number 80 in 2 ways:

```
1. Based on previous data
2. Just probability of number 80 occuring at least once in 5 balls
```

I know how to calculate the **2** part but the **1** st part is kind of tricky.

I am trying to use binomial probability which gives me some numbers but when I add up all probabilities it does not come out 1.0 thats how I know its wrong.

Formula Im using:

```
P(k out of N) = (N! / (k!(N-k)!)) * (p^k)(q^N-k)
```

where

```
N = 115 //115 Past drawings in total
k = 23 //number of times number 80 occured in that 115 drawings. Frequency
p = 5 / 80
q = 1 - p
```

Is this correct way of calculating it? Why all probabilities when added up does not add up to 1.0 ?

Should my **N** be number of total drawings or number of total frequencies

Comment: Your notation looks wrong.  Binomial distribution is $$p(k) = \binom{N}{k} p^k q^{N-k}$$

Comment: it seems same to me

Comment: If the probabilities did not all add up to $1.0$, then what did they add up to?

Comment: As long as it does - I have no idea what $pk$ means, but if it means that to you, then OK.

Comment: 0.879 something like that

Comment: pk i meant p to the k power

Comment: Should my N be number of total drawings or number of total frequencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are drawing the balls **without replacement**. Hence, a binomial distribution is inappropriate. Imagine that you randomly choose all $5$ balls at the same time, then sort them in increasing order. The total number of ways this can happen (since order doesn't matter) is $\binom{80}{5}$. Now how many ways can you choose $5$ balls such that exactly one of them is $80$ and exactly four of them are not $80$? The total number of ways this can happen (since order doesn't matter) is $\binom{1}{1}\binom{79}{4}$. Hence, the probability is:
$$
\dfrac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{79}{4}}{\binom{80}{5}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{79!}{75!4!}}{\dfrac{80!}{75!5!}}= \dfrac{5 \cdot 79!}{80!}= \dfrac{5}{80} = \dfrac{1}{16}
$$

Comment: but where do i use 115 total drawings in thi formula and frequency of number 80 coming up? This calculates what is the probability of number 80 to come up, but I want to calculate the probability of 80 based on previous data (previous 115 drawings out of which frequency of 80 was 23)

Comment: If you want to calculate an experimental probability, then you could approximate the probability by simply calculating $k/N=23/115=0.2$. As you increase the number of trials, this experimental probability should converge to the theoretical probability of $1/16$.

Comment: when I do k/N for all other numbers and add all probabilities does not add up to 1

Comment: It's not supposed to. For example, although it is extremely unlikely, it is technically possible that in all $N$ trials, you drew the number $80$. That would mean that $k/N=1$. **In the long run**, as you increase the number of trials, we expect the sum of all the $k/N$'s to converge to $1$.

Comment: sum returns 4.55778..... number does that seem right ?

Comment: That seems reasonable. I suggest that you run your program again, except this time increase the number of trials to a larger number; for example, try $N=10000$. The sum of the probabilities should be closer to $1$ than your current sum of $\approx 4.56$; for example, maybe the new sum will be somewhere in the interval $(0.9,1.1)$.

Comment: I was missing total drawings * 5 since its 5 balls and now it adds up to 1